# Soundcloud HTML5 Widget stops loading randomly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, widget, soundcloud

I'm developing a site with the Soundcloud HTML5 widget and am having trouble loading the widget. It was working fine, but after a lot of page refreshes during development, the widget stops loading. Clearing cookies doesn't work, but opening the page in incognito or a new browser does work. I'm assuming it has something to do with frequent page refreshes, which shouldn't be a problem in production, but it makes me nervous that it might seize up.

Does this issue sound familiar to anyone. The fact that clearing local storage and cookies does nothing, but it does work consistently in another browser or incognito confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at your console? (F12 in Chrome and IE), I have experienced these issues when I tried to load to many streams in a short time, preventing access to SoundCloud for a few.

Posting your code could help us give a more specfic answer.